# Multicolumn Combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am using **multi column** in combo box. So, I would like to put a space between the **stock_type** and **stock_type_dscription**. I tried the below coding but all the items in combo box replaced with **system.data.datarowview**.

```
 string sqlstk = "SELECT stock_type, stock_type_desc FROM stktype";
 SqlCommand stkcom = new SqlCommand(sqlstk, myconnection);

 SqlDataAdapter dastk = new SqlDataAdapter(stkcom);
 DataSet1 dsstk = new DataSet1();
 dastk.Fill(dsstk, "StockType");

 cboStk.DisplayMember = "stock_type" + " " +"stock_type_des";
 cboStk.ValueMember = "stock_type" + " " + "stock_type_des";
 cboStk.DataSource = dsstk.Tables["StockType"];
```

Anyone do know the way to allowed space put in multicolumn combo box, please help and guide.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the sql statement as below

```
 string sqlstk = "SELECT stock_type + ' ' +stock_type_des as combined FROM stktype";
```

and then

```
 cboStk.DisplayMember = "combined";
 cboStk.ValueMember = "combined";
```